# How can I use riverpod to rebuil my widget Animated?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

This is my code:

```
return AnimatedPositioned(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
  curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
  top: isSignupScreen ? 535 : 430,
  right: 0,
  left: 0,
  child: Center(
    child: Container(
      height: 90,
      width: 90,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          boxShadow: [
            if (showShadow)
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.3),
                spreadRadius: 1.5,
                blurRadius: 10,
              )
          ]),
      child: !showShadow
          ? Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [Colors.orange[200]!, Colors.red[400]!],
                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                      end: Alignment.bottomRight),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.3),
                        spreadRadius: 1,
                        blurRadius: 2,
                        offset: Offset(0, 1))
                  ]),
              child: Text(
                'GETIN', // Here typewriter effect
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              )
              )
          : Center(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

This code i use for my login page, in the same page I have "SignIn and SingUp" and I use "typewriter effect" in "GETIN" text, I already did that, but I would like to use the same effect when user click on SIGNUP with riverpod to show the text "GETUP" (is an example)

This is my code for "Typewriter effect":

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:teslo_app/config/constants/palette.dart';

class TypewriterEffect extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  const TypewriterEffect({super.key, required this.text});
  @override
  TypewriterEffectState createState() => TypewriterEffectState();
}

class TypewriterEffectState extends State<TypewriterEffect> {
  String _displayText = '';
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _startTypewriterEffect();
  }

  void _startTypewriterEffect() {
    const Duration delay = Duration(milliseconds: 200);
    const Duration typingDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 150);

    Timer.periodic(delay, (timer) {
      if (_currentIndex == widget.text.length) {
        timer.cancel();
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _displayText = widget.text.substring(0, _currentIndex + 1);
          _currentIndex++;
        });
      }
    });

    Timer(typingDuration, () {
      // Do something after the typing animation is complete
      // print('Typewriter Effect Complete');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(
          _displayText,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Palette.textColor1),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I do it with Riverpod?